# How to display a glyphcon in the angular ui-grid cell based on condition?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-grid

I have a angular UI-Grid. Here, in a column called 'Scenario name' lock glyphicon has to be displayed if that particular scenario has Is_Locked='T' in database.

To do this, i have called a method as shown below. This method returns the required cell template. But, it will be displayed as plain text and it is not converted to html.

Please suggest ideas.

Globalexternal scope method:

```
$scope.globalExternalScope = {
    BaselineLock: function (row) {
        if (row.entity.Is_Locked == 'T') {
            $scope.template = '<a ng-href="#/newScenario/">{{row.entity.Scenario_Name}}</a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>';
            return $scope.template;
        }
        else {
            $scope.template = '<a ng-href="#/newScenario/">{{row.entity.Scenario_Name}}</a>';
            return $scope.template;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling method from cell template:

```
CellTemplate:{{'<div>{{getExternalScopes().BaselineLock(row)}}</div>'}};
```

Comment: Maybe, you can make an empty `<span>` with `ng-class` expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I don't think you can do it that way, although your cellTemplate does reference getExternalScope**s** which isn't the name of your object, so maybe that's the problem. Even if it was the problem, this is a MUCH cleaner solution that won't require you to make unneeded calls.

You should be able to completely delete the BaselineLock() check and in your `gridOptions` add the following line to the columnDefs:

```
cellTemplate: 
    '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><a ng-href="#/newScenario/">{{row.entity.Scenario_Name}}</a><span ng-if="row.entity.Is_Locked == \'T\'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></div>'
```

I don't have your exact code, so I can't test this, but I've done something similar before using this style for font-awesome icons and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thats a great solution. But the only problem is when comparing with 'T' cell template is not accepting it and its a code error. May be 'T' value i have to get from some variable.

Comment: I used html escape sequence \'T\' and it works now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good catch. Updated the answer to reflect that. If this solution works for you, could you accept the answer?

Comment: I have another important question for you. Is it possible to have a button dropdown in ui-grid. Please provide an example on this. I hope it is also a cell template change. I tried but no luck.

Comment: That's probably possible, but I haven't done it before and it belongs in its own question.

Comment: Finally we solved this issue by using angular smart table. Smart table offers more options and easy processing compared to ui-grid.